# show the large text to edit like the textarea

Tags: html

**Featured on the cover of Business World as one of the ‘Ten Young Guns’ of the Indian marketing communications community (May, 2010)MBA from IIM, Calcutta .. We need a username and password protected client-login area, where they
can view and download files. Pls let me know your recommended placement
for this and the admin controls (add, upload, delete files).**

I have this text which is coming from database , When the user click on the update , it will go to the next page show all the values in INPUT TYPE ="TEXT" field . now my problem is when the text is small , its good and easily visible but when the text is larger like  the above example , its not visible like the textarea
So the user can see and edit large text but the textarea has not a feature  to show the text and my whole editable text in the form 
So any body can help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You can make an <input> text field larger by using the size attribute, or specifying  a width in CSS, but it will be confined to a single line, so you need to use a <textarea> to edit multiline content.

You can make the textarea larger using the rows and cols attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

You may need some server side logic based on the length of the text to output the correct form element.